# Problem for using PlayOnLinux

Tags: unity, 12.10, software-installation, playonlinux

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , so I have installed PlayOnLinux in order to get Ms Office 2010 in my ubuntu. I have succeeded to get Ms Office 2010, but my problem now is, when I open the 'Dash Home' and click on the shortcut icon of Word or PowerPoint, it's not responding and does not open.

- How to open the new installed Office programs?

Comment: Can you check your log files. They should be in your home folder: `~/.PlayOnLinux`. For example `"$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/MS Office/ MS Office.log"`. You can paste it in http://paste.ubuntu.com/ to share with us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply open PlayOnLinux and either:

1. double-click on the office applications shortcut
2. or mark the created shortcut, then hit 'Run', to open it.

If you haven't already created a shortcut of 'Word', 'PowerPoint', 'Excel' etc.. you ought to do so, the repeat step 1 or 2 from above.

- Also, you can directly open the application of choice `.exe`, by browsing into its dir `/home/USERNAME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/USERAPP` and 'right click'-> 'open with..'

[image]

Comment: Thank you a flowed these steps , and it become useful , know it's working perfectly ... thank you man

Comment: @ user263927: You are very welcome!!